# Making API request to another docker container (NextJS, NodeJS)

Tags: node.js, docker, docker-compose, next.js

I am having issues making API calls from my NextJS app to my NodeJS Express app. I am trying to call my api using the container name. I have set the proxy in my package.json file linking to the container. I am really struggling with Docker but I really want to use it for this app. I am pretty new to NextJS *and* Docker, but have experience in react and nodejs/express. I should also mention this was originally a CRA app but I migrated to NextJS.

NextJS package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.5",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.0",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.4",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^5.0.14",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "axios": "^1.2.2",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "next": "latest",
    "react": "latest",
    "react-cookie": "^4.1.1",
    "react-dom": "latest",
    "react-pdf": "^6.2.2",
    "react-spinners": "^0.13.7",
    "react-toastify": "^9.1.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "proxy": "http://api:8000"

}
```

NextJS Dockerfile:

```
# Dockerfile for production
# Install dependencies only when needed
FROM node:16-alpine AS deps

WORKDIR /frontend

# Install dependencies based on the preferred package manager
COPY package.json package-lock.json*  ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .


RUN npm run build

COPY . .

EXPOSE 3000

ENV PORT 3000

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

NodeJS Dockerfile

```
FROM node:16

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /server

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)
COPY package*.json ./

RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm ci --omit=dev

COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000

CMD [ "node", "index.js" ]
```

Docker Compose

```
version: '1.0'

services: 
    api: 
      build: ./server
      container_name: api
      restart: always
      ports: 
        - 8000:8000
      networks:
        - backend
        - frontend
    frontend:
      env_file: ./.env
      container_name: frontend
      depends_on:
        - api
      build:
        context: ./frontend
      ports:
        - 3000:3000
      networks:
        - frontend  


networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

When my app calls my API, it sends the request to 'http://api:8000/api/' as opposed to the actual address the API is running at.

I tried using the url string in my axios.default.baseUrl in my _app.js file, I expected that to work (it doesn't). I am also unsure if my docker images are rebuilding properly or if it is using a cached version/cached build files. I stop and delete my conatiners and images through the Docker Desktop GUI to try to prevent it from running a cached version. I also run `docker builder prune` to clear cache. I am running `docker-compose up -d` to build and run my container.

Comment: Make sure that your Node app is listening on port 8000. EXPOSE in a Dockerfile is only documentation and doesn't do anything, so your Node app could be listening on another port.

Comment: Is the NextJS application running in a browser (even if it's served from a container)?  The browser is outside the Docker environment and can't use container names as host names; you need to connect to published `ports:` of your services.

Comment: So this means I will need to connect directly to the URL of the server that the container is hosted on and the respective API port? What happens once I have this container running on many servers? Will I be out of luck?

Or maybe I can use location.hostname in my default base URL?